# MongoDB : How to Restructure Code to Scale When Field Arrays Become Too Large?

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.2

This quote sums up well how I spent my life today:

["Inevitably, everyone who uses MongoDB has to choose between using multiple collections with id references or embedded documents"](http://openmymind.net/Multiple-Collections-Versus-Embedded-Documents/)

**I'm experiencing what this quote is referring to as I consider the possible issue of scaling something like a thread - message relationship like the example below:**

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("2bjbkjb4234j134124"), //A ThreadID
    "messages" : [
        {
            "_id": ObjectId("56a7b13f24236dea1247cdc7"),
            "authorName" : "Nick", 
            "timestamp" : 1.453699391078E12, 
            "message" : "Hello"
        },
        ... plus 50,000 more similar messages
    ]
},
...
```

**I'm learning now that BSON document limit could create a scaling breakage.**

I was originally assuming that with horizontal scaling - A collection like "messages" broken down thread documents would be a logical relationship (for both a programmatically accessing messages and keeping the document sizes relatively smaller.)

YET, when you consider a factor like time(like 2 years go by), or for any other reason you could imagine, there is always the possibility of "messages" getting too large - then all a sudden we have a broken structure that horizontal scaling(from my limited point of view) doesn't fix.

**My Question:**

**How would you proactively defended against potential breakage like this? Would you recommend a reference like "threadID" be inside of each
message? Or could we at the collection level(sorry if this sounds stupid) - create dynamic names(e.g "messages.threadID1")?**